# When I save the return of the method it saves undefined

Tags: javascript

I've recently started learning JS and in this problem I have to do two methods, the first one creates an array with the cars that haven't been sold yet and the second has to create an array with the cars that haven´t been sold yet and are 0 km. I have to use the first method in the second one, but when I save the return of the first method it saves UNDEFINED. Thanks

```
let cars = require('./cars');

let concessionaire = {
  cars: cars,

  carsForSell: function() {
    let carsNotSold = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
      if (this.cars[i].sold == false) {
        carsNotSold.push(this.cars[i]);
      }
    }
    return carsNotSold;
  },

  newCars: function() {
    let aux = this.carsForSell();
    let zeroKm = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
      if (this.aux[i].km < 100) {
        zeroKm.push(aux[i]);
      }
    }
    return zeroKm;
  }
};
```

The structure of cars is

```
let firstCar = {
    brand: 'Ford',
    model: 'Fiesta',
    price: 150000,
    km: 200,
    color: 'Blue',
    dues: 12,
    year: 2019,
    patent: 'APL123',
    sold: false
};

let secondCar = {
    brand: 'Toyota',
    model: 'Corolla',
    price: 100000,
    km: 0,
    color: 'White', 
    dues: 14,
    year: 2019,
    patent: 'JJK116',
    sold: false
};

let cars = [firstCar, secondCar];

module.exports = cars;
```

Comment: First you need do declare your first car and second car before you are using those variables. Second you need to export concessionaire not cars. So do `module.exports = concessionaire;`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: cars is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method are correct, you have an additional `this` in your code:

```
 if(this.aux[i].km < 100){
```

`aux` is a local variable, `this` is wrong.

Working version:

```js
let firstCar = {
    brand: 'Ford',
    model: 'Fiesta',
    price: 150000,
    km: 200,
    color: 'Blue',
    dues: 12,
    year: 2019,
    patent: 'APL123',
    sold: false
};

let secondCar = {
    brand: 'Toyota',
    model: 'Corolla',
    price: 100000,
    km: 0,
    color: 'White', 
    dues: 14,
    year: 2019,
    patent: 'JJK116',
    sold: false
};

let cars = [firstCar, secondCar];

let concessionaire = {
   cars: cars,

  carsForSell: function(){
      let carsNotSold = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++){
         if(this.cars[i].sold == false){
            carsNotSold.push(this.cars[i]);
         }
      }
      return carsNotSold;
   },

   newCars: function(){
      let aux = this.carsForSell();
      let zeroKm = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++){
         if(aux[i].km < 100){
            zeroKm.push(aux[i]);
         }
   }
   return zeroKm;
   }
};


console.log(concessionaire.newCars())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declared "concessionaire" there is no variable "cars".

If you use let and const scope. you have to write cars first, so that "concessionaire" can use that value.